# The titleList is displayed incorrectly..?

Tags: android, kotlin, model, pojo

in logcat I'm getting

[Title 1  [6  Name 6, 7  Name 7], Title 2  [6  Name 6, 7  Name 7], Title 3  [6  Name 6, 7  Name 7]]

what I want  is

[Title 1  [1  Name 1, 2  Name 2], Title 2  [3  Name 3, 4  Name 4, 5  Name 5], Title 3  [6  Name 6, 7  Name 7]]

```
    var list:MutableList<Data> = ArrayList();
    val titlelist:MutableList<TitleList> = ArrayList()

    list.add(Data("1","Name 1"));
    list.add(Data("2","Name 2"));

    titlelist.add(TitleList("Title 1",list))
    list.clear()


    list.add(Data("3","Name 3"));
    list.add(Data("4","Name 4"));
    list.add(Data("5","Name 5"));

    titlelist.add(TitleList("Title 2",list))
    list.clear()


    list.add(Data("6","Name 6"));
    list.add(Data("7","Name 7"));

    titlelist.add(TitleList("Title 3",list))


    Log.d("TITLE_LIST",titlelist.toString())
```

My Pojo Classes are

Data.java

```
private String id;
private String name;

public Data(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

TitleList.java

```
private String title;
private List<Data> dataList;

public TitleList(String title, List<Data> dataList) {
    this.title = title;
    this.dataList = dataList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line which adds item to title list. In the constructor of TitleList, pass `ArrayList(list)` instead of `list` (Eg. `titlelist.add(TitleList("Title 2",ArrayList(list)))`). Do this for all 3 lines where you add items to title list. This is because if you use the variable `list`, this list is bound to the instance of title list you create and will change if you change the value of `list`. So the instance will always have the latest value you give to variable `list`. That is why you are always getting [6 Name 6, 7 Name 7] in all 3 cases.

Comment: Thank you. it's working perfectly, I also tried changing list = ArrayList() instead of list.clear() thats working too